# Return Multiple XML values in SQL using STUFF

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have following XML value in one of the column of table.

```
<wizard id="CF510D2B-BF9C-485B-9D33-0056D1DDFDF2" step="4" sbm="1C766093-633D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A">
  <reviews>
   <crd id="AE7F8E74-643D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A" />
   <rvw id="AF7F8E74-643D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A" />
   <rvw id="B07F8E74-643D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A" />
 </reviews>
</wizard>
```

Using following query

```
SELECT abc = STUFF((
        SELECT ',' +CAST(w.[state].value('(/wizard/reviews/rvw/@id)[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') AS varchar(max)) 
        FROM dbo.Wizard w where code='1C766093-633D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A'
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
 FROM dbo.Wizard w
```

Output:

```
AF7F8E74-643D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A
```

Desired output:

```
AF7F8E74-643D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A,B07F8E74-643D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `[1]` only gets the first match since you are using the `value` function. You can use the `nodes` function with `value` to concatenate the values with the technique you started.

```
SELECT abc = STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Review.value('@id', 'uniqueidentifier'))
    FROM dbo.Wizard w
        CROSS APPLY w.[State].nodes('/wizard/reviews/rvw') Reviews (Review)
    WHERE Code = '1C766093-633D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A'
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Here is a fully functional example if it helps since I'm assuming your tables and desired output in above code:

```
DECLARE @Wizard TABLE (Code UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, [State] XML)
INSERT @Wizard VALUES ('1C766093-633D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A', 
    '<wizard id="CF510D2B-BF9C-485B-9D33-0056D1DDFDF2" step="4" sbm="1C766093-633D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A">
      <reviews>
       <crd id="AE7F8E74-643D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A" />
       <rvw id="AF7F8E74-643D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A" />
       <rvw id="B07F8E74-643D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A" />
     </reviews>
    </wizard>')

DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Review.value('@id', 'uniqueidentifier'))
    FROM @Wizard w
        CROSS APPLY w.[State].nodes('/wizard/reviews/rvw') Reviews (Review)
    WHERE Code = '1C766093-633D-E611-80C2-40F2E9DD0D2A'
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
SELECT @Text
```

Comment: Yes, [1] only gets the first one.  I have always used [1] in the query. when I tried [2] it got second match.But I wasn't aware of how to get multiple values. Select query is exactly what I am looking for ! Thank you for your help.  :)